# How to get the following !isset to work when doing an email activation

Tags: php

This is really weird because all of my other email activation form is working when I include the !isset function but not for this file.

I even tried to echo all the get variables and everything seems to be working fine...

```
<?php
include_once __DIR__ .'/../header2.php';

if (!isset($_GET['email']) || !isset($_GET['userid']) || !isset($_GET['id']) || !isset($_GET['reply_registration_expirydate'])) {
   echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=../index.php?activate=missinglink'>"; 
   exit();
} else {

  include_once __DIR__.'/dbh.php';
  $reply = 0;
  $email = strip_tags($_GET['email']);
  $username = strip_tags($_GET['userid']);
  $userid = strip_tags($_GET['id']);
  $reply_registration_expirydate = strip_tags($_GET['reply_registration_expirydate']);


   if (empty($_SESSION['key'])) {
        $_SESSION['key'] = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
      }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" 
   rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
   type="text/css" 
   href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="reply_registration">
        <h2>Reply Registration against spam</h2>
    </div>
<div class="reply_registration">
<form class="signup-form" action="../reply_registration_form.php" method="POST">
    <label>Why do you want to join PianoCourse101?</label>
    <br></br>
    <textarea name="joined" placeholder="Why do you want to join PianoCourse101?"></textarea>
    <br></br>
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($username); ?>">
    <br></br>
   <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($email); ?>">
    <br></br>
    <input type="hidden" name="expirydate" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($reply_registration_expirydate); ?>">
    <br></br>
     <input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['key']; ?>">
         <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit Reply Registration</button>
      </form>
```

[image]

Comment: What errors/issues are you facing? It is not clear what you are trying to ask

Comment: I am not getting any errors and all thee get variables are getting through but it is just taking me to the missing link page

Comment: I know it sounds strange and that it should work but I am not sure why it is not working...

Comment: I am still not sure why I am getting the white page.. I am thinking that it could be a header issue but not sure as there are no errors

Comment: This is so frustrating here..... I have even added the header file